# my app should work like this when i open pushing notification the PSUICollectionView navigate to secound screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

my app should work like this when i open pushing notification the PSUICollectionView navigate to second screen

how could I do it in objective "any hint"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in didReceiveRemoteNotification you can pass object with key and while click on it manage like below

```
NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);

    if ([[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"notification_type"] integerValue]] integerValue]==1) {

        GlobalVariables *global=[GlobalVariables getInstance];
        global.NotificationView=1;

        if (![CommonMethods stringIsEmpty:global.user_id] && ![CommonMethods stringIsEmpty:global.user_name]) {

            NewsViewController *news=[[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:nil];
            [_controller pushViewController:news animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

from server side you can pass like this

```
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'sound' => $sound);
$body['notification_type'] = $not_type;
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier '_controller'
where can I declared _controller and how ??